# What is this icon button showing?

Tags: gnome, 16.04

Just trying Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Beta1. There's an icon I don't recognise in the user menu:

[image: screenshot]

What does it do? If I click it the menu vanishes and next time I peek in it's got a padlock. What is it locking?

Comment: seems to be to lock an auto-turn function of a tablet or it is used to active turn between landscape and potrait orientation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This icon is designed to be used with mobile devices (like phones and tablets) built with a gyroscope.

It controls the auto-rotation feature, which allows you to rotate your device to a portrait or landscape rotation, which will rotate the contents of the screen to fit the orientation.

On desktops and most laptops, this option does nothing and can be ignored.